# How to manually create a datadog event metric

Tags: datadog

I'm creating my dashboard, and I have the following two metrics: `event.sent` and `event.failed`. Fortunately, I still haven't had any failed events (knock on wood), so this metric does not exist yet on datadog.

But I want to create it so I can add it to my monitors. How do I manually create this metric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1, dirty:

Duplicate the definition of `event.sent` in `event.failed`. As soon as you restart the agent, any `sent` event will be seen as `sent` **and** `failed`. After a minute or so you revert the definition of `failed` to the proper definition, but you now have a few (admittedly bogus) failed event in datadog, allowing you to use the metric.

## Solution 2, clean:

On your datadog dashboard, edit the relevant metric, and instead of using the graphical interface (tab `edit`) got to the `JSON` tab, where you can manually enter your metric name (probably a slightly updated cut & paste of your `sent` metric), no matter if an event exists or not.

Comment: Not bad.  But it would be great if it were possible to have the metric display "0" in the mean time.  At least for the case of a "query value" style block.